# How can I release an update to an iOS app that uses CoreData with Xcode 4.6.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I've released an iOS app that uses a basic CoreData model to track its data. That data model has never changed. I've created an enterprise release of the app with Xcode 4.6.1. When I install that release over my previous release on a device & try to run it, I'm greeted with:

```
...
NSStoreType = SQLite;
        NSStoreUUID = "7DFC22FD-805E-4AED-B5F8-B1AE1FC829A8";
        "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
    }, reason=Can't find model for source store}, {
        URL = "file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/D8B9F67D-9B00-439D-AC06-2582EBBE2441/Documents/YourMother.sqlite";
        metadata =     {
            NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 419;
            NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
...

Mar 26 16:52:02 iPad backboardd[63] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.your.mother[0xdbef]' exited abnormally with exit status 255
```

How can I create an update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Xcode 4.5 to create the release.